# Limit number of parallel threads in NUnit Project

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am running selenium test in parallel in an NUnit project and want to limit the number of test that are run at a time

Solution I found says to specify:`[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(N)]` to AssemblyInfo.cs, but my NUnit project does not have an AssemblyInfo.cs

I want to limit number of selenium test run executed in parallel in NUnit project

Comment: You can add an `[assembly]` level attribute outside the namespace of any .cs file, not just an `AssemblyInfo.cs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/LevelOfParallelism-Attribute) says might, it is not mandatory to be in *AssemblyInfo.cs*:

> The following code, which **might** be placed in AssemblyInfo.cs

---

You could add `[assembly:LevelOfParallelism(3)]` to your test fixture .cs file. Take a look more about assembly attribute [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/set-assembly-attributes).

```
using System;

[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(3)]

namespace YourNamespace
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class YourTextFixture
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Note: you can always add an AssemblyInfo.cs to your NUnit project. Just add a file named AssemblyInfo.cs at the top level, and you can add any assembly flags there.